# g++ compile and link options

Tags: gcc, g++

naive question perhaps, are there separate lists of compile and link options for g++, I mean a list that shows which options are for compiling and which are for linking. gcc manual says these are the link options

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

and the options other than these are compile options? I am confused while reading the Definite Guide to GCC.

Answer (score 6):

There is a grouped list of [all options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). With [overall options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) such as -c and -o and specific [c++ options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you read the manual for `gcc` (what you referring to with your link seems to be a version of it, but check `man gcc` on your machine too), you will find that it has well labelled sections such as "C++ Language Options", "Language Independent Options", "Linker Options" etc. I think this is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

These option apply specifically in the way described on the linking stage, and some other options may affect the input/output and general behaviour while linking too. So I would say No, options other than this set are not exclusively compile options.

Consider that you also have options for the preprocessor and other stages of compilation.