# can someone explain the difference between the two c compiling commands?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation

the first compiling command is :

```
GCC -c file.c -o file.o
```

the second command is :

```
GCC file.c -o file
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [g++ compile and link options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538516/g-compile-and-link-options)

Answer (score 1):

The `-c` option tells the compiler to run just the compilation step and create an object file.

By omitting this option the compiler also performs linking to create an executable.